# How to split a vector of CLI arguments into pairs in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

I have e.g. `-m 4 -y 2016` and want to end up with `[["-m" 4] ["-y" 2016]]` or maybe a map. How do I split them into pairs?

Answer (score 4):

To split them into pairs, use [partition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition):

```
dev=> (partition 2 ["-m" 4 "-y" 2016])
(("-m" 4) ("-y" 2016))
```

To make a map, [apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) [hash-map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map) to it:

```
dev=> (apply hash-map ["-m" 4 "-y" 2016])
{"-y" 2016, "-m" 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [special library for that](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli).

```
(let [cli-options [["-m" "--max MAX" "M description"
                        :parse-fn #(Integer/parseInt %)]
                       ["-y" "--year YEAR" "Year"
                        :parse-fn #(Integer/parseInt %)]]]
        (-> "-m 4 -y 2016"
            (str/split #"\s")
            (parse-opts cli-options)))
=>
{:options {:max 4, :year 2016},
 :arguments [],
 :summary "  -m, --max MAX    M description\n-y, --year YEAR  Year",
 :errors nil}
```